# Interpretations of $f(z)=1/z$ and $\varphi(z)=e^{\frac{1}{\log(z)}}$ as complex maps

Tags: complex-analysis

The reciprocal function $f(z)=1/z$ can be thought of as the composition of two mappings: “inversion in the unit circle” and conjugation (i.e. reflection about the real axis).

> Is there an analogous interpretation of $\varphi(z)=e^{\frac{1}{\log(z)}}$ as a mapping?

To create $\varphi(z)$ from $f(z)$ I first let $f(x)=1/x$ for $\Re(x),$ then mapped $h:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ with $h(x,y)=\big(e^x,e^y\big)$ to get $\varphi(x)=e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}.$ Then did $x\mapsto z,$ for $z\in \Bbb C.$

I'm really curious about this. To figure this out I looked up an example for $f(z)$ and tried to replicate it for $\varphi(z):$

$$ w=e^{\frac{1}{\log(z)}}=e^{\frac{1}{\log(re^{i\theta})}}=e^{\frac{1}{\log(r)+i\theta}} $$

However I can't offer an interpretation off the top of my head from this.

Comment: No as $f$ is a meromorphic function, while $\phi$ needs a branch cut (as well as avoiding the principal value at $1$ to make that point non-singular - unless you take as branch cut the positive reals axis of course)

Comment: oh so there's no interpretation of $\varphi$ as the composition of two mappings?

Comment: obviously you can write it as a composition (straightforward $\exp$ and $1/\log$) but what is the point? For $1/z$ one has a nice geometric description but here I am not sure there is anything "nice"